# Multiplication of two variables for linear problems in glpk (gusek)

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I'm trying to implemenet an assignment problem. I have the following problem when trying to multiply two variables in linear programming (using glpk gusek) in my goal function:

```
minimize PATH_COST: sum{k in Rodzaj_Transportu}(sum{z in numery_Zlecen}Koszty_Suma[k,z])*y[k,z]; #y is a binary variable; Koszty_Suma is total cost for ordez z and car type k
```

The following error is arising: "model.mod:47: multiplication of linear forms not allowed".

Code (.dat file):

```
data;

set numery_Zlecen := 1, 2, 3; #order numbers

set Miasta := '*some data: *' #cities.

#order numer (from city to city)
set Zlecenie[1] := Warszawa Paris;
set Zlecenie[2] := Berlin Praha;
set Zlecenie[3] := Praha Amsterdam;

#number of packages for transport for a particular order
param Ilosc_Wyrobow := 
1 10
2 50
3 110;

param Godziny_Pracy := 9; #number of working hours during the day
param Pojemnosc_Samochodu := 35; #capacity of the car (how many packages it can take)
param Srednia_Predkosc := 80; #average car speed
param Spalenie_Paliwa := 0.25; #fuel combustion
param Wynagrodzenie_za_Godzine := 20; #salary for one working hour
param Cena_Noclegu := 100; #price of accommodation

param Dystans: '*some data: *' #km between cities.
param Koszt_Paliwa : '*some data: *' #fuel consumption depends on country.
end;
```

Code (.mod file):

```
#INDEXY
#=====================================================================
set Miasta;                 #i,j
set numery_Zlecen;              #z
set Zlecenie{numery_Zlecen} dimen 2;    #p,q
set Rodzaj_Transportu;          #k

#PARAMETRY
#=====================================================================
param Dystans {Miasta,Miasta};
param Ilosc_Wyrobow{numery_Zlecen}; 
param Godziny_Pracy >= 0;
param Pojemnosc_Samochodu {Rodzaj_Transportu}>= 0;
param Srednia_Predkosc >=0;
param Spalenie_Paliwa >=0;
param Koszt_Paliwa {Miasta,Miasta};
param Wynagrodzenie_za_Godzine >= 0;
param Cena_Noclegu >= 0;

#ZMIENE
#=====================================================================
var x{Miasta,Miasta,numery_Zlecen} <= 1, >= 0; #variable x equal 1 when we're going the path from city A to city B; otherwise it equals 0
var y{Rodzaj_Transportu,numery_Zlecen} binary <=1, >=0; #variable that shows what types of car/s we are using for order (can be 0 or 1)
var Koszty_Suma{Rodzaj_Transportu,numery_Zlecen}; #total costs
var Koszty_Transportu{numery_Zlecen}; #transport costs
var Koszty_Odpoczynku{numery_Zlecen}; #rest costs
var Koszty_Wynagrodzenia{numery_Zlecen}; #salary costs

#FUNKCjA CELU
#=====================================================================
minimize PATH_COST: sum{k in Rodzaj_Transportu}(sum{z in numery_Zlecen}Koszty_Suma[k,z])*y[k,z];

#OGRANICZENIA (constraints)
#=====================================================================
s.t. SOURCE{z in numery_Zlecen, (p,q) in Zlecenie[z], i in Miasta: i = p && p != q}:
sum {j in Miasta} (x[i ,j ,z ]) - sum {j in Miasta}( x[j ,i ,z ]) = 1;

s.t. INTERNAL {z in numery_Zlecen, (p,q) in Zlecenie[z],i in Miasta: i != p && i != q && p != q }:
sum {j in Miasta} (x[i ,j ,z ]) - sum {j in Miasta}( x[j ,i ,z ]) = 0;

s.t. OGR_KM_DZIEN{z in numery_Zlecen,(p,q) in Zlecenie[z], j in Miasta, i in Miasta: i != q}:
if (Dystans[i,j] > (Godziny_Pracy*Srednia_Predkosc)) and i != q then x[i,j,z] = 0;

s.t. OGR_KOSZTY_SUMA{z in numery_Zlecen, k in Rodzaj_Transportu}:
Koszty_Suma[k,z] = (Koszty_Transportu[z] + Koszty_Odpoczynku[z] + Koszty_Wynagrodzenia[z])*ceil(Ilosc_Wyrobow[z]/Pojemnosc_Samochodu[k]);

s.t. OGR_KOSZTY_TRANSPORTU{z in numery_Zlecen}:
Koszty_Transportu[z] = (sum{i in Miasta} (sum{j in Miasta} ( Dystans[i,j]*x[i,j, z]*Koszt_Paliwa[i,j] ) ))*Spalenie_Paliwa;

s.t. OGR_KOSZTY_ODPOCZYNKU{z in numery_Zlecen}:
Koszty_Odpoczynku[z] =
(sum{i in Miasta} (sum{j in Miasta} ( Dystans[i,j]*x[i,j, z] ) ))/(Godziny_Pracy*Srednia_Predkosc) * Cena_Noclegu;

s.t. OGR_KOSZTY_WYNAGRODZENIA{z in numery_Zlecen}:
Koszty_Wynagrodzenia[z] = 
((sum{i in Miasta} (sum{j in Miasta} ( Dystans[i,j]*x[i,j, z] ) ))/(Srednia_Predkosc)) * Wynagrodzenie_za_Godzine; 

s.t. OGR_Y_JEDEN{z in numery_Zlecen}:
sum{k in Rodzaj_Transportu}(y[k,z]) = 1;
solve;
```

How is it possible to get rid of this error? Any hints how to solve this kind of problem are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think the parentheses are incorrect (note that y[k,z] depends on z). The expression

```
  sum{k in Rodzaj_Transportu}(sum{z in numery_Zlecen}Koszty_Suma[k,z])*y[k,z];
```

is not mathematically correct. So, I assume what you meant is:

```
sum{k in Rodzaj_Transportu}(sum{z in numery_Zlecen}Koszty_Suma[k,z]*y[k,z]);
```

Let me restate the problem a little bit. I assume we can write this as:

```
sum((i,j), x[i,j]*y[i,j])
```

with `y` a binary variable and `x` a continuous variable.  I also assume `0 <= x[i,j] <= U[i,j]`. (U is an upper bound).

Here is a way to **linearize** this quadratic term. We can introduce a variable `z[i,j]=x[i,j]*y[i,j]` using the following inequalities:

```
 z[i,j] <= U[i,j]*y[i,j] 
 z[i,j] <= x[i,j]
 z[i,j] >= x[i,j]-U[i,j]*(1-y[i,j])
 0 <= z[i,j] <= U[i,j]
```

Now you just can `minimize sum((i,j),z[i,j])`. For a similar linearization see [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2020/06/simplify-solutions.html).

Comment: But here we need to get : min sum(Koszty_Suma[k,z])*y[k,z]) in the end. So, how we can emplement it here if we don't actually know the upper bound of Koszty_Suma[k,z] variable? Is there any way to connect them using constrains? Or somehow redefine our problem in different way so we can connect x and y? @ErwinKalvelagen

Comment: What you write is mathematically incorrect. It is nonsensical.

Comment: thank you very much)  Now I see the problem but I still have one question. My x variable have 3 parameters (if I can say so) and y have 2 paramiters. And they have only one common paramiter. Should I make a new variable (let say i named it 'b') with four indexes, so it will be b[i,j,z,k]?

Comment: These things are called indices (parameters are very different things). But yes: `b[i,j,z,k]=x[i,j,z]*y[z,k]` would be an example.