# What does Big M method do in constraints when converting nonlinear programming into linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, opl

I got a question regarding this constraints in the paper. This paper says it used big M method in order to make non-linear programming model into LP. I get that big number M[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE7ts.png)is a huge number, but I don't get what big number M[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE7ts.png) really does on the constraints. Would you guys give me some insight on the use of the big M in this constraints?
Below is constraints with big number M[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE7ts.png).

The paper says these constraints are
when K[m][i] = p[i]*x[m][i],

```
maximize sum(m in M, i in I) (K[m][i]-c[i]*x[m][i]     
K[m][i]-M[1]*(1-x[m][i]) <= p[i]
K[m][i]+M[1]*(1-x[m][i]) >= p[i]
K[m][i]-M[1]*x[m][i] <= 0
```

it originally looked like this in non linear programming

```
maximize sum(m in M, i in I)(p[i]-c[i])*x[m][i]
```

So, basically, converting nonlinear programming into linear programming led to a little change in some decision variables and 3 additional constraints with big number M.

Here is another constraint that includes big number M.

```
sum (j in J) b[i][j]*p[j]-p[i]<= M[1]*y[i]
```

which originally looked like

```
p[i]<sum (j in J) b[i][j]*p[j], if y[i]==1
```

Here is the last constraint with big number M

```
(r[m][j]=p[j])*b[i][j]*x[m][i] >= -y[i]*m[1]
```

which was

```
(r[m][j]-p[j])*b[i][j]*x[m][i](1-y[i])>=0
```

in nonlinear program.

I really want to know what does big M do in the model.
It would be really appreciated if anyone gives me some insight.

Thank you.

Comment: One other thing - you mentioned 'that big number M1is a huge number'. It really should NOT be a huge number. It needs to be as small as it can be and still work, so it typically can be chosen from the known data. Try using a value just bigger than the biggest value that could appear in the other terms in that expression. Using too big a value for M can lead to numerical issues and instabilities.

Comment: A slightly better formulation is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140335/multiplication-of-two-variables-for-linear-problems-in-glpk-gusek/62140567#62140567

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the big-M is used to model the non-linear constraint

```
K[m][i] = p[i] * x[m][i]
```

in case `x` is a binary variable. The assumption is that `M` is an upper bound on `K[m][i]` and that `K[m][i]` is a non-negative variable, i.e. `0 <= K[m][i] <= M`. Also `p` is assumed to be non-negative.

Since `x[m][i]` is binary, we can have two cases in a feasible solution:

1. `x[m][i] = 0`. In that case the product `p[i] * x[m][i]` is 0 and thus `K[m][i]` should be zero as well. This is enforced by constraint `K[m][i] - M * x[m][i] <= 0` which in this case becomes just `K[m][i] <= 0`. The two other constraints involving `M` become redundant in this case. For example, the first constraint reduces to `K[m][i] <= p[i] + M` which is always true since `M` is an upper bound on `K[m][i]` and `p` is non-negative.
2. `x[m][i] = 1`.  In that case the product `p[i] * x[m][i]` is just `p[i]` and the first two constraints involving M become `K[m][i] <= p[i]` and `K[m][i] >= p[i]` (which is equivalent to `K[m][i] = p[i]`). The last constraint involving `M` becomes `K[m][i] <= M` which is redundant since `M` is an upper bound on `K[m][i]`.

So the role of `M` here is to "enable/disable" certain constraints depending on the value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

to model logical constraints you may either use logical constraints or rely on big M

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/difference-between-using-indicator-constraints-and-big-m-formulation

I tend to suggest logical constraint as the default choice.

In https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/

let me share the example

[How to multiply a decision variable by a boolean decision variable in CPLEX ?](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/multiplybinarybydecisionvariable.mod)

```
// suppose we want b * x <= 7 

    dvar int x in 2..10;
    dvar boolean b;

    dvar int bx;

    maximize x;
    subject to
    {

    // Linearization  
    bx<=7;



    2*b<=bx;
    bx<=10*b;

    bx<=x-2*(1-b);
    bx>=x-10*(1-b);

    // if we use CP we could write directly
    // b*x<=7

    // or rely on logical constraints within CPLEX
    // (b==1) => (bx==x);
    // (b==0) => (bx==0);
    }
```