# How to convert the following if-else conditions to Linear integer programming constraints?

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, linearization

if x ≥ 100,
then x -100 + p(x) ≤ 0;
else p(x) ≤ 0
p(x) is a linear function. We can add x ≥ 0 if it could make it easy.

I tried to make a binary variable z, if x ≥ 100, then z＝1; else z＝0. Then we got z(x-100)+p(x) ≤ 0. However, the term z(x-100) is nonlinear, we couldn't use it.

Comment: Please move this from Stack Overflow to Operations Research.

Answer (score -1):

Some well-known tricks for describing such conditions (e.g., Either/Or and If/Then) as linear constraints can be found in [this book](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118166000) (Applied Integer Programming: Modeling and Solution). See Section 3.6 (Transform Nonsimultaneous Constraints). Based on the technique described in Subsection 3.6.5, the condition **if x ≥ 100, then x -100 + p(x) ≤ 0** can be linearized using the following two constraints:

- x < 100 + M * y1
- x - 100 + p(x) ≤ M * (1 - y1)

In the above constraints, y1 is a binary decision variable, and [M is a big number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184702/what-does-big-m-method-do-in-constraints-when-converting-nonlinear-programming-i). It should be noted that the first inequality is strict; But you can readily convert it to a non-strict one. See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2673917/can-a-linear-program-have-strict-inequalities).

On the other hand, the condition **if x < 100, then p(x) ≤ 0** can be enforced by the employment of the following two linear constraints in which y2 is again an auxiliary binary decision variable, and [M' is a big number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184702/what-does-big-m-method-do-in-constraints-when-converting-nonlinear-programming-i):

- x ≥ 100 - M' * y2
- p(x) ≤ M' * (1 - y2)